# I want to use a checkbox to alter a var's output

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, var

I have looked everywhere, and I cannot seem to find anything that does what I need it to do.  I would love for my script to check against the vars I have put in for date and time and automatically calculate DST, but that is way more involved than I can get.  Instead, I just want a simple checkbox to subtract an hour from the var's attributes.

```js
  
/*Define Zones*/
  var edt = values[3];
  var pdt = values[3];
  var cet = values[3];
  
/*This is for the timezone calculator*/

if ( ((values[0] == 'march') && (values[1] > '8')) || (values[0] == 'april') || (values[0] == 'may') || (values[0] == 'june') || (values[0] == 'july') || (values[0] == 'august') || ( (values[0] == 'november') && (values[1] != '1')) ) {
  edt = values[3] - 3;
  pdt = values[3] - 6;
  cet = values[3] - - 1;
} 
else {
  edt = values[3] - 4;
  pdt = values[3] - 7;
  cet = values[3] - - 2;
}

  /*This puts the world time clock in */
var anchor = 'http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?iso=2015-' + a_month + '-' + a_date + 'T' + values[3] + ':' + values[7] + ':00';

  /*Subtracts the hours for CET/PDT/EDT 
  var edt = values[3] - 3;
  var pdt = values[3] - 7;
  var cet = values[3] - -2;
*/
  var times = [values[3], edt, pdt, cet];

  /*This is for the the pluralization of hours */
  /*English hour text */
  if (values[4] == '1') {
   var hourtext = 'hour';
  } 
  else { var hourtext = 'hours';
  }
  /* FR hour text */
  if (values[4] == '1') {
   var frhourtext = 'heure';
  } 
  else { var frhourtext = 'heures';
  }
  /*DE hour text */
  if (values[4] == '1') {
   var dehourtext = 'stunde';
  } 
  else { var dehourtext = 'stunden';
  }

  /*This is to validate the checkbox */
var validate = 'Not Checked';

if ($('.ckDst').is(':checked')) {
    edt = values[3] - 4;
  pdt = values[3] - 7;
  cet = values[3] - - 2;
} else if {
  edt = values[3] - 3;
  pdt = values[3] - 6;
  cet = values[3] - - 1;
}
else {
}
 
  
  
 /*This is to put in DST */
   if ($('.ckDst') == ':checked') {
  edt = values[3] - 4;
  pdt = values[3] - 7;
  cet = values[3] - - 2;
  } 
  else { 
  edt = values[3] - 3;
  pdt = values[3] - 6;
  cet = values[3] - - 1;
  }
```

I have the full code, with HTML and CSS here: http://codepen.io/GrayHogan/pen/RWreKL

While I will gladly take all suggestions, I really just want the danged checkbox to do what I tell it to!

Thanks!

Comment: What does the jQuery Validate plugin have to do with your question?  Please be more mindful when tagging.  Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Sparky; I had used the validate as a means before with the checkbox. I forgot that I had removed the function and placed in a var instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that you are listening for when the check box gets checked or unchecked.

Try this

```
$('.ckDst').on('change',function(){
    if ($('.ckDst').is(':checked')) {
        edt = values[3] - 4;
        pdt = values[3] - 7;
        cet = values[3] - - 2;
    } 
    else { 
        edt = values[3] - 3;
        pdt = values[3] - 6;
        cet = values[3] - - 1;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
Also fixed the if statement being defined wrong as pointed out in the comment.

Comment: `if ($('.ckDst') == ':checked')` isn't a valid conditional, comparing object to string

Comment: Yes you are right that is another problem with the script, I will fix

Comment: no it's not .... first item is an object and will never be equal to the string. Something like `this.checked` or `$(this).is(':checked')` is more appropriate

Comment: Yes I just understood what you said, sorry I updated the answer

Comment: I tried this as listed, and for whatever reason it is not doing anything. The hours don't actually change when I click generate.  Would this be a better method of trying to do what I want?            if ( ((values[0] == 'march') && (values[1] > '8')) || (values[0] == 'april') || (values[0] == 'may') || (values[0] == 'june') || (values[0] == 'july') || (values[0] == 'august') || ( (values[0] == 'november') && (values[1] != '1')) ) {
  edt = values[3] - 3;
  pdt = values[3] - 6;
  cet = values[3] - - 1;
} else {
  edt = values[3] - 4;
  pdt = values[3] - 7;
  cet = values[3] - - 2;
}

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of your script, I was simply answering the question on why the check conditional wasn't working, looks like you'll have to build on that I showed a bit to make it work the way you need it to.